# How Do I Get Output From My NsLookup Program into JTextArea in Seperate Program

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, nslookup

I am just wondering how I would get the output from a seperate NsLookup program into a TextArea in my NsLookupGUI program?

I have an ActionListener;

```
private class buttonPressed implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
                getText = userInputBox.getText();

        lookup.resolve(getText);

        results.append(getText + "\n"); 
        }
```

to call the Nslookup class. However, the output is displayed in the terminal rather than the TextArea.

The piece of code below is my NsLookup program;

```
public class NsLookup {

    private InetAddress iNet = null;

    public void resolve(String hostName) {
    try {
    iNet = InetAddress.getByName(hostName);

    System.out.println("Host Name: " + iNet.getHostName());
    System.out.println("IP Address is: " + iNet.getHostAddress());
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setText()` method of the text area object.

`textareaobj.setText(...)`

Answer (score 0):

If needed, you can also reassign System.out to a custom OutputStream that prints to the text area.